# MvcSitemapProvider doesn't show level 4

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

My breadcrumb only shows 3 levels deep.
The 4th level is an empy Node list (in SiteMapPathHelperModel).
Did I miss some configuration?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Board" area="board" controller="menu" action="index">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Members" area="board" controller="Board" action="index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="New" area="board" controller="Board" action="create" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit" area="board" controller="Board" action="edit" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" area="board" controller="Board" action="details" />
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Groups" area="board" controller="group" action="index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="New" area="board" controller="group" action="create" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit" area="board" controller="group" action="edit" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" area="board" controller="group" action="details" />
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Responsabilities" area="board" controller="responsability" action="index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="New" area="board" controller="responsability" action="create" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit" area="board" controller="responsability" action="edit" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" area="board" controller="responsability" action="details" />
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't post any routes or URLs, I can't tell you specifically what you have missed. However, you are most likely missing the "id" parameter of the "create", "edit", and "details" nodes (or whatever you have decided to call it).

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit" area="board" controller="Board" action="edit" preservedRouteParameters="id" />
```

See the [working demo](https://github.com/NightOwl888/MvcSiteMapProvider-Remember-User-Position) titled "MvcSiteMapProvider-Forcing-A-Match" and the [related article](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position) that shows how to properly nest the nodes for CRUD operations and also how to fix up the display when using this approach.